# 32 bit process on 64 bit OS

Tags: windows-server-2008, 32bit-64bit

1. What is the max RAM a 32 bit process can access in a 64bit OS? It is 2 gigs or full 4 gigs?
2. Is there a way to make it access more maybe by enabling PAE on process level?

Thanks.

Comment: It all comes down to whatever your specific OS gives the process, and I don't see a tag specifying what OS you're asking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most applications will only have access to 2Gb when running on WOW64, however if the 32 bit application has the `IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE` flag set then it will be allocated 4Gb of virtual address space, if it does not then it will only get 2.

See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384219%28VS.85%29.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

A 32bit process on a 64Bit OS can address a full 4 gigs of memory.  Sorry I don't have any links to back this up but prior to doing IT I ran a graphics department doing 3d animation and compositing and ran many 32bit processes on 64bit OS's.